# How to Implement Nivo Slider in Yii Framework Application?

Tags: php, yii, nivo-slider, yii-extensions

I've downloaded Nivo Slider and reviewed it's readme and tutorials.  However, I'm using it within the Yii Frameowrk and am not sure how to render it therein.

Thus far, I've added the following to my view:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->regiserPackage('nivo-slider');
Yii::app()->clientScript->render();
```

The package is registered in main.php as:

```
 'nivo-slider'=>array(
            'basePath'=>'/protected/exensions/nivo-slider',
            'css'=>array('nivo-slider.css'),
            'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
            'js'=>array('jquery.nivo-slider.js'),
            ),
```

My images are outside of the document root in a spearate directory.  How do I configure Nivo to read the images out of that directory?  What must be included in my view to simulate a DIV containing the HTML required to render the slider?

Comment: Are you talking about any yii extension? then please provide the extension name and link

Comment: here almost full documentation for install, usage: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nivoslider/#hh8

Comment: @Sergey It looks like this extension has issue with JQuery 1.4?  Have you been able to make it work?

Comment: @dInGd0nG No, I was hoping to avoid the whole extension route if possible.

Comment: @SidC i suggest you to use the above linked extension and replace the js and css files in it for the compatibility with jquery 1.4